# How can a read-only purpose data connection to MS Excel/Access from MS Excel prevent the MS Access file from being locked to edits?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-access, multiple-users

My concern is that I use MS Excel to make a data connection with several MS Access/MS Excel files, but there is no writing involved. The only thing the data connection is used for is to extract data. But then the users wanting to write on the database are unable to because making a data connection will lock the MS Access/MS Excel files for edits. So is there a way I can establish a read-only data connection while allowing others to edit and save on the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how you are setting up your data links, you should be able to specify the following Data Link Property:

[image: Share Deny None]

Setting `Share Deny None` will allow others to open the Access Database file in full `ReadWrite` mode.

If you already have a connection you would like to modify, you can use the following steps to add `Share Deny None` to the connection string:

- Open 'Existing Connections' and select the connection you want to modify.
- Click 'Properties' and switch to the 'Definition' tab.
- In the 'Connection String' box you will need to add/modify the following value:

`Mode=Share Deny None;`

Example:

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;User ID=Admin;
Data Source=E:\Documents\Test.accdb;Mode=Share Deny None;Extended Properties="";
...
```

Comment: This looks promising. Will try it out tomorrow.

Comment: If it helps, I tested this at home and was able to import an Access DB into Excel, open the DB in Access and modify some values, then save and refresh the data in Excel and watch the table update with the new values from Access.

Comment: That's what I need although where can you find the `Data Link Properties`? In the `Existing Connections` I cannot find any option for this.

Comment: @Pherdindy See my edit to the answer for that.

Comment: Thanks. This solves the half of my issue. The other half is that when the MS Access file is being used, it is locked and makes me unable to establish a data connection from my MS Excel file. Although I asked it in a separate question because it's a different issue.

Comment: You mean already in use before the connection is made? I'm not sure there's any way around that one unfortunately...

Comment: Yes because the people making inputs to the MS Access file may have the file open somewhere in the network. So when it's open, I cannot establish a data connection from Excel. I am waiting if someone has an answer to my other question, but if there isn't, then i'd have to use a script to save and close the Excel file then copy the Access files to a location in the network and it just keep repeating on a time interval.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for is a contradiction in terms.

The best you may do is keep two copies of the files, one to be read-only and the other updatable,
with periodically updating the read-only copy at times that it is not in use.

Comment: How do I update them with the condition it is not in use though? I use xcopy script and task scheduler of windows to run the script every 4:30 but if the file connecting to it is open, it will fail

Comment: Instead of copying over the file, you can rename the old file and copy in the new one. Renaming still works even when the file is in use.

Comment: I need an automated solution though. Is there a way to do so without manually renaming the files?

Comment: You may add it to the script.

Comment: So when i'm connected to an MS Access file for instance from my MS Excel file, I can rename the MS Access file to a different name, then paste the newer MS Access file? What happens if I refresh the data connection? Will it update to the new Access file without the need to restart my MS Excel file??

Comment: This sequence should work : user u1 accessing read-only, read-only renamed and new version copied, u1 closes and reopens the new read-only. This depends on the actions taken by Access which I'm not using. If your case is that a read-only file may stay opened for several days, but your script runs every day, you would need an incrementing element in the name to rename such as the date.